# Your project does not reference ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" framework. Add a reference to ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"

Tags: .net, frameworks, nuget, project

**Visual Studio Version**:
2019
**Summary**:
I have two framework projects in  same folder, 4.7 framework project has  local Nuget Package reference and   4.5 framework project has  local Assembly reference. The reported issue occurs when run 4.5 project after run the  4.7 projects

Issue:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Your project does not reference ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" framework. Add a reference to ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" in the "TargetFrameworks" property of your project file and then re-run NuGet restore.

**4.7 Project**

```
  <ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf" Version="1.1.19" />
</ItemGroup>
```

**4.5 Project**

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf" xmlns="">
  <HintPath>..\resources\Assembilies\Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

**Steps to Reproduce**:

1. Run 4.7 project with nuget reference
2. run 4.5 project  with assembly reference
3. will reproduce the reported issue

How to solve this issue

Comment: Seems legit, .net framework only supports backward version compatibility. On the first run Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.dll is generated in 4.7. It is not overriden on the second run so it crashes.

Comment: why can't you upgrade the 2nd project in 4.7 ?

Comment: @B.Lec Cleaning bin and Obj fix the issue but it needs to be calls before the build Starts

Comment: @B.Lec No i need those projects in both framework

Comment: Why are they in the same folder ?

Comment: @B.Lec That is my requirement , i need to keep this in same folder

Answer (score 20):

If anyone is ever stuck on a legacy project, the solution in the end was to delete the contents of bin and obj folders, and the .vs directory for the solution.

Comment: this helped for me: I removed .vs, bin, obj from the source folders for every assembly mentioned in the errors (not entire solution).